# a question about $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is:

Let $X$ consist of a sequence $\{x_m\}$ and let $\{p_m\}$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers. For any subset of $A \subset X$, let

$$
\mu(A) = \sum_{x_m \in A } p_m
$$
Then $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure.

This question is from Avner Frieman book, *Modern Analysis*. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: This problem just amounts to restating the definition of $\sigma$-finite, since you already have a countable cover of $X$ consisting of finite measure sets given to you.

Comment: **Hint**:  $X=\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \{x_m\}$. You know  that for $m$, $\mu( \{x_m\})=p_m<+\infty$. Recall the definition of $\sigma$-finite measure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. (1) Recall the definition of $\sigma$-finiteness. (2) Let $X = \{x_m \mid m \in \mathbf N\}$ and write $X_n = \{x_m \mid m < n\}$. What can you say about $\mu(X_n)$? And $\bigcup_n X_n$?